# Вывести слова в обратном порядке, оставив на месте символы и числа

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм, сортировка

Логику вроде понял, но при компиляции устойчиво выводит то же значение, которое задается. Подозреваю, что
не то значение возвращаю, но возможно ошибаюсь. Вот что набросал:

`Main` класс:

```
public class AnagramApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String reverse = "a1bcd efg!h";
        Anagram anagram = new Anagram();
        String reversedText = anagram.SortingMethod(reverse);
        System.out.println(reversedText);
    }
}
```

Основной алгоритм:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Anagram {
    
    public String reverseThis(String text) {
        String[] letters = text.split(" ");
        return Arrays.stream(letters).map(this::SortingMethod).collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
    }

    public String SortingMethod(String letter) {
        char[] lettersArray = letter.toCharArray();
        int startBorder = 0;
        int endBorder = lettersArray.length - 1;
        while (startBorder < endBorder) {
            if (Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[startBorder]) &&
                    Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[endBorder])) {
                char temp = lettersArray[startBorder];
                temp = lettersArray[endBorder];
                lettersArray[endBorder] = temp;
                startBorder++;
                endBorder--;

            } else if (Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[startBorder]) && !Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[endBorder])) {
                endBorder--;
            } else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[startBorder]) && Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[endBorder])) {
                startBorder++;
            } else {
                startBorder++;
                endBorder--;
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(lettersArray);
    }

}
```

Comment: Вывести должно что-то вроде d1cba hgf!e

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public String SortingMethod(String letter) {
    char[] lettersArray =
            letter.toCharArray();
    int startBorder = 0;
    int endBorder = lettersArray.length - 1;
    while (startBorder < endBorder) {
        if (!Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[startBorder]))
            startBorder++;
        else if (!Character.isAlphabetic(lettersArray[endBorder]))
            endBorder--;
        else {
            char temp = lettersArray[startBorder];
            lettersArray[startBorder] = lettersArray[endBorder];
            lettersArray[endBorder] = temp;
            startBorder++;
            endBorder--;
        }
    }

    return String.valueOf(lettersArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну как-то так можно попробовать (костыльно):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String reverse = "a1bcd efg!h";
    String[] words = reverse.split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (String str : words) {
        builder.append(reverseString(str)).append(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(builder.toString().trim());
}

public String reverseString(String str) {
    HashMap<Integer, Character> map = new HashMap<>();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(chars[i])) {
            map.put(i, chars[i]);
        } else
            result.append(chars[i]);
    }
    result.reverse();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Character> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        result.insert(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: выглядит страшно

Comment: @Andrew но работает)

Comment: справедливо) Просто дело в том, что я только учусь, а тут некоторые вещи я впервые вижу. Так что вряд-ли удастся мне таким костылем решить.

Answer (score -1):

Этот код работает с обычными символами и с *суррогатными парами*:

```java
// исходная строка
String str = "1q !i";
// строка исключаемых символов
String exStr = "! ";
// список кодовых точек строки
List<Integer> cpList = str.codePoints().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
// список индексов для исключения
List<Integer> iList = IntStream.range(0, cpList.size())
        // цифры или исключаемые символы
        .filter(i -> Character.isDigit(cpList.get(i))
                || exStr.indexOf(cpList.get(i)) > -1)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
// новый список без исключаемых символов
List<Integer> nList = cpList.stream()
        // не цифры и не исключаемые символы
        .filter(cp -> !Character.isDigit(cp) && exStr.indexOf(cp) == -1)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
// разворачиваем список
Collections.reverse(nList);
// возвращаем исключаемые символы на прежние места
iList.forEach(i -> nList.add(i, cpList.get(i)));
// новая строка
String nStr = nList.stream().map(Character::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
// вывод
System.out.println(nStr); //i1 q!
```